# How to return a multidimensional character array from a function in a header file in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a main file, and a header file.

In main file, I want to return a 2D char array from a char function from header file. My char function is as following:

```
char character_distribution(int length, char redistribution[length][2])
{
        char *buffer, distribution[256][2] = {0};
        long lSize;
        struct Bar result = funct();
        buffer = result.x;
        lSize = result.y;
        length = collect_character_distribution(buffer, lSize, distribution);
        reorganize_character_distribution(length, distribution, redistribution);

        return redistribution;
}
```

And my main function is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "character_distribution.h"

void main()
{
        int length;
        char distribution[length][2];
        distribution = character_distribution(length, distribution[length][2]);
        int a;
        for(a = 0; a < length; a++)
        {
                printf("%c\n", distribution[a][0]);
        }
}
```

When I run my code, I get the following error:

```
warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast
```

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Your function need to be of type `char **` to return a 2-d array .

Comment: Also, `length` is uninitialized in your program .

Comment: Yes, I have done. But I still get the same error.

Comment: @ameyCU you certainly do NOT need the return type to be `char **` to return a 2-dimensional array. In any case you should never return a pointer to a (non-static) function-local variable from the declaring function.

Comment: so, ameyCU, could you write me a full answer?

Comment: @davmac Here you see , array is passed to function and copy is created and modified but it would be fine to return it and store functions return in an array in calling function . **Note** - array is not declared in called function .

Comment: @ameyCU it would indeed be fine to store the result in an array provided by the calling function, as a pointer. But the type of that pointer would not be `char **`. That is not a pointer to an array, it is a pointer to a pointer. They are not the same thing. The correct type would be `char *([2])`, ie you would declare the parameter like `char *(inarray[2])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void character_distribution(int length, char redistribution[][2])
{
    char *buffer, distribution[256][2] = {0};
    long lSize;
    struct Bar result = funct();
    buffer = result.x;
    lSize = result.y;
    length = collect_character_distribution(buffer, lSize, distribution);
    reorganize_character_distribution(length, distribution, redistribution);
}
int main()
{
    int length = 2; //initialize
    char distribution[length][2];
    character_distribution(length, distribution);
    int a;
    for(a = 0; a < length; a++)
    {
        printf("%c\n", distribution[a][0]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If you really have to return the 2d array, one way (easy way) is to just put it in a struct

```
struct distribution_struct {
    char x[256];
    char y[2];
};
struct distribution_struct character_distribution(int length, char redistribution[][2]) {
    struct distribution_struct dis;
    //initialize the struct with values 
    //return the struct 
}
```

And another way is to manually allocate memory for the 2d array in the function and return it

```
char** character_distribution(int length, char redistribution[][2]) {
     //use malloc to create the array and a for loop to populate it 
}
```

Comment: Lukas, I call the function from a header file. It is not in the same file.

Comment: This will work even in that case because you're passing the pointer to the array when you call the function and the function will do the modification on that same array

Comment: can you explain what the function is supposed to do briefly? I might be able to help

Comment: the function inside of the header file gives me redistribution 2D array, and the length. I want to call these values from the main function in main file.

Comment: But according to your code, redistribution is whats passed and it was never changed in the function so there isn't really any reason to return it. 
Can you explain though what does the function do? there might be easier way

Comment: Lukas, I need to return that redistribution value from that header file. Because I will get this value in main function, and send it to another header file. I vitally need that value.

Comment: I added how to do that in the answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93926/discussion-between-yusuf-and-lukas).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot actually return an array from a C function. You can, however, return a pointer to such an array. The correct declaration in that case is:

```
char (*character_distribution(int length, char redistribution[][2]))[][2]
```

Sizing the initial dimension is not necessary and not, I suspect, actually conformant with standard C (at least, sizing it with `length` as you did in your question looks dubious to me). This is because arrays are passed by reference implicitly (and in this case, returned by reference explicitly) and it is not necessary to know the first dimension in order to calculate the address of an element having been given a pointer to the array (and the indices).

Note that you should not return a pointer to an array that is scoped locally to the function, since its storage is deallocated once the function returns (and such a pointer would then be invalid).

However, your question shows that you don't really need to return an array. Since arrays are passed by reference anyway, altering the passed-in array will causes changes that are also visible to the caller. Your code could be written as:

```
void character_distribution(int length, char redistribution[][2])
{
        char *buffer, distribution[256][2] = {0};
        long lSize;
        struct Bar result = funct();
        buffer = result.x;
        lSize = result.y;
        length = collect_character_distribution(buffer, lSize, distribution);
        reorganize_character_distribution(length, distribution, redistribution);
}
```

And

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "character_distribution.h"

void main()
{
        int length = 256;   // you need to initialise this...
        char distribution[length][2];
        // No assignment needed here!:
        character_distribution(length, distribution /* [length][2] - remove this! */);
        int a;
        for(a = 0; a < length; a++)
        {
                printf("%c\n", distribution[a][0]);
        }
}
```

(Of course this relies on the various other functions you call performing as they are supposed to).

Comment: thank you for your answer davmac. Could you share your full answer with me, involving two full functions?

Comment: Thank you for your full answer davmac. Currently I get this error on main function while calling character_distribution on distribution parameter: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘character_distribution’ makes pointer from integer without a cast

Comment: @yusuf fixed now, sorry. You were trying to pass a single element of the array when the whole array was required.

Comment: Thank you davmac. Do you have an idea, why I'm getting segmentation fault error?

Comment: @yusuf I do not, and in any case I do not have all your code. I suggest to post a separate question with a minimal compilable example that reproduces the problem if you are unable to debug it yourself.

Comment: davmac, the remaining code works perfectly. I have tested it already.

Comment: @yusuf, maybe it does, but I have no idea what "works perfectly" means in this context because I can't see the code for them (and you haven't otherwise described what they do). _Something is wrong_ - that is about all I can meaningfully say.

Answer (score 0):

Change the signature to this:

```
char** character_distribution(int length, char redistribution[length][2])
```

You are returning a **multidimensional** array, not a character.

Comment: try adding an explicit cast to char** : distribution = (char**) character_distribution(..........)

Comment: A multidimensional array is NOT the same as a `char **`.

Comment: adding an explicit cast is never the solution, the error you get without the cast is telling you that you're doing it wrong; the solution is to fix your code, not tell the compiler to hide the error message